# how to capture built-in camera with opencv and nodejs over internet?

Tags: node.js, opencv

I'm working on a streaming project that stream from my pc camera to my website

I do it fine but at `localhost` via
`cv.VideoCapture(0)`

Now I want to deploy my project

my project code is

```
const wCap = new cv.VideoCapture(0);
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("public/index.html", { root: __dirname });
});

setInterval(() => {
  const frame = wCap.read();
  const image = cv.imencode(".jpg", frame).toString("base64");

  io.emit("image", image);
}, 30);
```

what can I do to solve my problem?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: new cv.VideoCapture(0) is work only on local